# Tokenizing first and last name as one token

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

Is is possible to tokenize a text in tokens such that first and last name are combined in one token? For example if my text is:

```
 text = "Barack Obama is the President"
```

Then:

```
text.split()
```

results:

```
['Barack', 'Obama', 'is', 'the, 'President']
```

how can I recognize the first and last name? So I get only

```
['Barack Obama', 'is', 'the', 'President']
```

as tokens.

Is there a way to achieve it in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, going by definition of the word "token". What you're looking for is either a "[chunker](http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=NP_Chunking_%28State_of_the_art%29)" or a "[Named Entity Recognizer](http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=Named_entity_recognizers)". Some of these are written in Python, and some are not. But that should not matter, as you will be using the output of one of these in your (Python) pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you have an example that specifically talks about first and last name chinking?

Comment: @TJ1 I recommend this: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml